# Generating google directions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method `CustomGoogleDirections`

```
class CustomGoogleDirections < GoogleDirections
  @@base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml"
end
```

Which i call in my controller to find the location based on a hash:

```
@locations = @all_locations.each_cons(2).with_index.with_object({}) do |((e1, e2), i), h|
  h[i + 1] =
    [e1, e2,
     CustomGoogleDirections.new(e1, e2, key: Figaro.env.google_translate_secret_key).distance_in_miles, CustomGoogleDirections.new(e1, e2, key: Figaro.env.google_translate_secret_key).drive_time_in_minutes.url]
end
```

This result in the error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?destination=60%2BBarron%2BRoad%252C%2BDubai%252C%2BDubai&key=######################&origin=60%2BAlFhaged%2BRoad%252C%2BDubai%252C%2Dubai)
```

It used to work well before I did a rails upgrade.
Does anynone knows what I am missing please?

(When I used the generated xml link, it does load properly with all the long/lat informations)

Comment: Is using a gem that hasn't been updated since 2016 a good idea? Methinks not. Like why on earth would you use XML instead of the JSON endpoint?

Comment: The meat of that gem is only 100LOC. I would just write your own.

Comment: Yup, that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by modifying the gem, changing :

```
@url = @@base_url + '?' + @options.to_query
@xml = open(@url).read
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(@xml)
@status = @doc.css('status').text
```

to :

```
@url = @@base_url + '?' + @options.to_query
@response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(@url))
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(@response.body)
@status = @doc.css('status').text
```

It works locally but not sure about this as the right approach.